# systemctl start depending on tty

Tags: arch-linux, tty, startup

I would like to start Apache automatically on my machine, but only if I login from TTY1 (I do not run a display manager). If I log in from any other TTY, it should not start. I tried this in my `bash_profile`:

```
[[ -z $DISPLAY && $XDG_VTNR -eq 1 ]] && systemctl start httpd
```

But this does not work. Other commands DO work like this, so I assume the issue is permission related (only `su` can run `systemctl`). Is there another way to start the httpd server that is TTY dependent?

I am running Arch (see [this page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Start_X_at_Login) for how X is start upon login without a display manager, for instance).

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Apache normally starts at boot time, it has nothing to do with anyone logging in. Have you configured Apache not to start at boot time? Do you want to stop Apache when you log out?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start a daemon per-TTY and per-user, then there are two simple solutions:

1. Don't use `systemctl`.
   In this case, run `httpd` directly from your `.xinitrc` or in your shell rc as you mentioned in your post.
2. Use `systemctl --user`.
   This is not recommended for the moment because user sessions are not terribly stable, nor officially supported.

---

Frankly, I'm still trying to figure out why you would want to start a service like `httpd` per-TTY.

Answer (score -1):

In Ubuntu there's a script perl (perhaps heritage from debian: `/usr/bin/deb-systemd-invoke`) that maybe can result useful for you at least to check if it runs or not and with which `errorcode` it exits.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# vim:ts=4:sw=4:expandtab
# © 2013 Michael Stapelberg <stapelberg@debian.org>
#
# All rights reserved.
#
# Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
# modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:
#
#     * Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
#       notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
#
#     * Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
#       notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
#       documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
#
#     * Neither the name of Michael Stapelberg nor the
#       names of contributors may be used to endorse or promote products
#       derived from this software without specific prior written permission.
# .
# THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY Michael Stapelberg ''AS IS'' AND ANY
# EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED
# WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE
# DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL Michael Stapelberg BE LIABLE FOR ANY
# DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES
# (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES;
# LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND
# ON ANY THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT
# (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
# SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.

=head1 NAME

deb-systemd-invoke - wrapper around systemctl, respecting policy-rc.d

=head1 SYNOPSIS

B<deb-systemd-invoke> start|stop|restart S<I<unit file> ...>

=head1 DESCRIPTION

B<deb-systemd-invoke> is a Debian-specific helper script which asks
/usr/sbin/policy-rc.d before performing a systemctl call.

B<deb-systemd-invoke> is intended to be used from maintscripts to start
systemd unit files. It is specifically NOT intended to be used interactively by
users. Instead, users should run systemd and use systemctl, or not bother about
the systemd enabled state in case they are not running systemd.

=cut

use strict;
use warnings;

if (@ARGV < 2) {
    print STDERR "Syntax: $0 <action> <unit file> [<unit file> ...]\n";
    exit 1;
}

my $policyhelper = '/usr/sbin/policy-rc.d';
my @units = @ARGV;
my $action = shift @units;
if (-x $policyhelper) {
    for my $unit (@units) {
        system(qq|$policyhelper $unit "$action"|);

        # 104 means run
        # 101 means do not run
        my $exitcode = ($? >> 8);
        if ($exitcode == 101) {
            print STDERR "$policyhelper returned 101, not running '" . join(' ', @ARGV) . "'\n";
            exit 0;
        } elsif ($exitcode != 104) {
            print STDERR "deb-systemd-invoke only supports $policyhelper return code 101 and 104!\n";
            print STDERR "Got return code $exitcode, ignoring.\n";
        }
    }
}

exec '/bin/systemctl', @ARGV;
```